# Does the controller go back to the supply after use?

Tags: space-park

Does the controller go back to the supply after use? The rulebook (which I can’t find online) doesn’t seem to specify, but there is mention of it being in the supply after the beginning of the game, and I don’t see any badges that would put it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [this thread on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2036600/scout-and-controller-question):

It only gets returned to the supply in solo. When not playing solo, the controller doesn't go back into the supply.

[Pre-production Rulebook](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KwYhPowuBGWoYYiXoZe54Bc-5jwvE00xmBTrAkpWfAY/edit):

> Whenever any player (including the player with the Controller) visits a destination with Scout on it, the player with the Controller may choose to gain a Sun Crystal or a Fast Travel token from the supply.

> ### Solo Mode: Playing Against Scout
>
> If you visit the same destination as Scout, you must spend a Sun Crystal or return the Controller to the supply.

[Tabletopia Rulebook](https://tabletopia.gcdn.co/games/space-park/rules/rulebook-v2/en):

> When any player visits a
> destination with Scout on it, the player with the Controller may choose
> to gain a Sun Crystal or Fast Travel pass from the supply.

> ### Solo Mode
>
> [...] if you wish to visit a destination with
> Scout, you must spend a Sun Crystal or return the Controller
> to the supply.

Comment: I'm checking my physical copy right now, which doesn't match your Google doc. Are those from preproduction?

Comment: Yeah. I found it from the kickstarter page. https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/keymastergames/space-park

Comment: @Jessy I found a newer version on Tabletopia. I've edited my answer to include that.